# Adobe Illustrator: How to center or assign position for project window on screen

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Adobe Illustrator. I am working on two versions of a project, in two window tabs, at the same time. I want to compare these two windows. However, the position of the "viewport" of these two window tabs are different. I want to place the window views exactly identically for both, so that when flipping between tabs, they are positioned in the same place (in order to see their differences easily).

Is there a way to center the project window relative to the screen (or app window dimensions) or otherwise place the window at a specific position (similarly like you can assign the zoom level)?

**Project window 1:**

[image]

**Project window 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called *Fit On Screen* which will center the active artboard and change the zoom so the artboard fits the screen.

Simply double-click the *Hand Tool*:

[image]

Or select it from the "zoom menu" in the lower left corner:

[image]

If you want to zoom out a bit, don't use the *Zoom Tool* as it will move the center, instead choose the zoom factor from the zoom menu.

Answer (score 1):

`View > Fit All In Window` then change the zoom level to your desired amount - do this for *both* windows and they should have identical positioning.

Windows **won't** automatically adjust to match position/zoom between each other. (Which is kind of the point of having multiple windows for the same file.)